# simulating hyperlink.target="_parent" with response.redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how can I simulate hyperlink.target="_parent" with response.redirect in ASP.NET codebehind (C#), I want to redirect to a page (from code behind) but as I'm in a 2-frame window, the whole page should be redirected, i.e. something like hyperlink.target="_parent", I suppose it should be possible via JavaScript, can you give some help please? I want something cross-browser of course

thanks

Comment: I've found a solution for this problem: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Load", "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.location.href = 'mainpage.aspx'; </script>");, it worked, but is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate other frames/windows only on the client-side (through javascript, user interaction etc.)

`Response.Redirect` is a server-side construction; the server doesn't know anything about your frames and cannot perform the necessary action. The workaround could be *to say* the page to execute javascript code when it will be returned to the client.

So `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` method (you already mentioned it in your comment) could be the best option here.